# Помогите с решением задачи...

Tags: c

> Начав тренировки, спортсмен в первый день пробежал 10 км. Каждый день он увеличивал норму на 10% нормы предыдущего дня. Какой суммарный путь пробежит спортсмен за 7 дней?

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int i = 0;  
int n = 6; // из 7 дней осталось 6, так как первый день он уже бегал  
float norm = 10;  
float normUp = 1.1;

for(i=0; i<n; i++){  
  norm *= normUp;  
}

print(norm);
```

Комментарий DL_:

```
int i = 0;  
int n = 6; // из 7 дней осталось 6, так как первый день он уже бегал  
float norm = 10;  
float normUp = 1.1;   
float sum=norm;   
for(i=0; i<n; i++){   
    norm *= normUp;   
    sum +=norm;   
}      
print(sum);
```

Comment: Разве не так?

 int i = 0;
 int n = 6; // из 7 дней осталось 6, так как первый день он уже бегал  
 float norm = 10;
 float normUp = 1.1;
 float sum = norm;
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  norm *= normUp;
  sum += norm;
 }

 print(sum);

Comment: Да, так. Шаришь. =)